# Add an number to title.parameterize to pass uniqueness validation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am creating a slug for a Posts on an `after_create` callback and am not sure how to append a number to the end if the slug already exists.

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :slug
  after_create :create_slug
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug

  def create_slug
    existing = Post.where("slug LIKE ?", "#{title.parameterize}%").length
    existing > 0 ? slug = "#{title.parameterize}-#{existing+1}" : slug = title.parameterize
    self.update_attributes(slug: slug)
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because my `where` clause matches a post with the title "Some title That is Different", for example.

One solution would be to append `post.id` instead of trying to enumerate. This might also be better in the case that posts are deleted. But I'm not expecting to delete any posts, and not using IDs seems more meaningful.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would

```
Post.where(title: title).count
```

give you the correct number in your situation?

It is important to also put a unique constraint on the slug column in the DB, because this algorithm is subject to a race condition if two posts are created with the same title at a similar time. Rails itself cannot guarantee column uniqueness.

Comment: The reason I was skeptical of using that was because, for example `"Some title: and more".parameterize` returns the same slug as `"Some title and more".parameterize`. So comparing titles isn't always going to pass the uniqueness validation. (Editing question to add that in)

Comment: Wrap the block in a begin/rescue and if you catch a uniqueness exception then increment the suffix by 1 and try again. Appending post.id is a common pattern, so with a url blahblah-1234, the controller actually does a params[:slug].split('-').last to get the Post id, but the URL still looks nice for Google and the user. eg. any article on http://theconversation.com

Comment: hmm, I guess I can just do db IDs and run a rake task for existing posts. Not a fan of the begin/rescue idea though, not sure why.